# Reading an 8-byte double from an 4-byte double saved in a binary file

Tags: c++, binary

I got a binary file with some doubles, chars and others. I have to read the file and perform numerical operations with the doubles in it.

To read the file, I do something like this:

```cpp
std::ifstream infile("../numbers.bin", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);

if (!infile.is_open()) {
    std::cerr << "Could not open file.";
    return 1;
}

while(!infile.eof()) {
    long first = 0;
    double second = 0;

    infile.read((char *) &first, sizeof(first));
    infile.read((char *) &second, sizeof(second));
    double result = first * second;
    std::cout << first << "*" << second << " = " << result << std::endl;
}
```

However, I get something like this (which looks wrong):

```
-4397703785598681083*4.77479e-314 = -2.09981e-295
```

I took out a hex editor and looked at the file, it looks like the saved double has only 4 bytes, instead of the 8 on my machine (I'm using Linux, the binary was built on a Windows machine.

My assumption is I try to put a 4-byte double which looks something like this in hex: `642a 0940` into an 8-byte double, which results in something like this: `642a 0940 0000 0000` stored to memory and thus results in a wrong double representation.

So, my actual question is: Is there a way to put this 4-byte double in a correct way into an 8-byte double? I think it should be somehow possible to either prefix this with leading `0`s.

I also know I could change the settings of my compiler to let doubles have only 4 byte instead of 8 or I could just use floats instead of doubles.
This is more out of curiosity of wanting to understand how this works and why it doesn't in this case.

**EDIT:** I tried using a `float` instead of a `double` which did not work. The result was `-4397703785598681083*2.14321 = -9.42521e+18`

Comment: A "4 byte double" is called float.

Comment: Why not reading as `float` and then convert to `double` (if necessary)?

Comment: Why the `long`? What is the actual file format? How was it saved?

Comment: @user207421 The format was a `.bin`, it was created using a different c++ program.

Comment: @tkausl I've honestly overlooked that. The note I got with the file was "This number at that position is a `double` so I was focused on using a `double` and not a `float`.

Comment: @tkausl I've tried using a float, see the my updated question.

Comment: @kolaente: As tkausl points out, it's likely a `float`. Endianness might be an issue. However, we're certain of one thing. It is **not** a `double`. Regardless of compiler settings or OS, a double is **at least** 8 bytes, You might get 10, perhaps, but not 4.

Comment: You've got a lot of hacking to do. The only guarantee that C and C++ make about binary files is that you can read data that was written by **the same program**. When you're dealing with two different programs you have to have a common data protocol; that is, you have to know the exact format of the data in the file in order to be able to read it. Calling it `float` or `double` is a start, but it doesn't tell you the details that you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
while(!infile.eof()) {
    long first = 0;
    float second = 0;

    infile.read((char *) &first, sizeof(first));
    infile.read((char *) &second, sizeof(second));
    double result = first * second;
    std::cout << first << "*" << second << " = " << result << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, got this: `-4397703785598681083*2.14321 = -9.42521e+18`. It does not look like a float works.

Comment: You need to know exactly what format the data was written to the file to read it then. The answer is only to your question “how to read a 4 byte double”